# TableViewController issue: won't save user input from textView

Tags: swift, tableview

Update:
so goal of this to save the text that user enters in a UITextView in cell, so that the text is saved for that particular cell number and does not duplicate, move or remove the text.

as suggested I am trying to handle the textViewdidChange func inside of the custom cell, by doing the following:

```
var onTextEntered: ((String?) -> ())!

func setup() {
    notesTextView.delegate = self
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    onTextEntered(notesTextView.text)
}
```

making a string that holds the text and then adding the text to the String every time textViewDidChange is called (trying to explain this to myself as we go along, so please correct me if my explanation needs it).

next in CellForRowAt

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "TableViewNotesCell"

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TableViewNotesCell





    cell.setup()

    cell.onTextEntered = {input in

        if let text = input {

            self.cellText[indexPath.row] = text // here is the error (index out of range)

        }


        if indexPath.row < self.cellText.count {
            cell.notesTextView.text = self.cellText[indexPath.row] ?? "placeholder"
        }
    }

    return cell

}
```

when I do the above code, as soon as textViewDidChange is called (when i type a single letter or digit in textView) the I get the error : "Fatal error: Index out of range" on the line which I use the array of cellText[indexPath.row] = text. please help or let me know if my understanding of the process is wrong would love to learn!

Comment: I don't understand what you ultimately want to achieve. Can you more clearly explain what it exactly is that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes: as it says in the question I have 3 func of this tableViewController and one of them is NOT working. tableViewcontroller I am trying to create a tableViewController which has a button and a textView in each cell, and has following functions: 1. add a cell when bar button item in toolbar is pushed (works)

when button is pushed, textView becomes unEditable and checkmark appears on top of button (works)
when scrolling up and down cell a.k.a. dequeueing cell, the cells, which has user input, saves the cell to the indexPath.row and thereby saving the text to the indexPath(not working)

Comment: I need to save the text of the textView inside of cell and then add it to the cell which had the text data in the first place, when it is displayed (or dequeued) again.

Comment: You just copy and paste your original post. Things like “saving the cell to indexPath.row” make no sense, for instance. Is all that you’re trying to do is take input from a cell and add it to some collection in the view controller?

Comment: the reason I am doing this is that when I scroll up and down the cell with user input duplicates, gets removed or appears in a different place. so my solution is to add the text input from textView which is inside of  a cell, save it in an array, and then when the cell is shown or dequeued it only adds the text if it is the cell of the correct indexPath

Comment: The caveat with reusing cells is that if you don’t set the property of everything in the cell for every cell, then this stuff happens. Even if one cell has no input, for example, you need to explicitly code that in the cell. You cannot leave any properties in the cell empty, such as nil text from a text view. Make sure you’re setting every property, even nil when it can be nil, in the table data source for each cell. Otherwise the data source might reuse a cell with leftover data from the last reuse. Make sense?

Comment: well yeah I think, but I dont understand how to implement this, what more configuration does table view data source need other than: section = 1 and numberOfRowsInSection = cellNumber.count ?

Comment: Edit your question and include the data source and the cell itself.

Comment: hey if you could check out the update I made that'd be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save for every single edit

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // inside cellForRowAt

    cell.textView.delegate = self

    cell.textView.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

@objc func textViewDidChange(_ tex: UITextView) { 

    cellEndEdit[tex.tag] = tex.text!

}

class VC:UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {
```

---

give default values for the array

```
 var cellEndEdit = [String](repeating: "", count: numberOfRows)
```

Comment: Ok so what you do in the code is 1.delegate textView to the TableViewController, 2: set tag of textView to indexPath.row 3. in the textViewDidChange func set the add an object to array of text? could u please explain, and also the textViewDidChange updates on every letter input, did you mean to use textViewDidEndEditing

Comment: ok but I already used that func inside the tableViewController does that matter?

Comment: does not work, the func of textViewDidChange error is can only be used in: ...." look at the update on the bottom of the post I've posted the code snippet there

Comment: wheres the return cell ?

Comment: add it , the answer is a skeleton not all

Comment: okay well, if u just add the return cell after those two lines then how would the cell get the text added into its TextView ?

Comment: the delegate will trigger the function when you edit the textview and save that value to the array  `cellEndEdit`

Comment: okay sure, but where is the text form the array put into the textView of cell?

Comment: the code put inside of the func textViewDidChange makes the same error as all of my own attempts:( index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, that you tableView has a variable number of cells, and all of them have a UITextView, whose content should be recorded and indexed, I would recommend to create a custom UITableViewCell, that handles the textView itself.

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView() 
    var onTextEntered: ((String?) -> ()) //that's a callback

    func setup() {
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    override func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        onTextEntered(textView.text)
    }
}
```

Since you're working with a sorted list of user inputs, you should have your array at hands, in which you can store and from which you can retrieve data. So if some data already exists, grep through your array and fill the cells that deserve it. Also define the `onTextEntered` callback here to tell the cell what to do, if it gets called (in your case, store the text of the UITextView in your array).

```
//your carrier, if you store the already existing user inputs some where, map them in here
//depending on how you calculate the number of cells, this array has to have the same size so use the same logic for this
var yourStringCarrierArray: [String?] = [] 

override func tableView(_ tableview: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.setup()
    cell.onTextEntered = { input in
        if let text = input {
            self.yourStringCarrierArray[indexPath.row] = text
        }
    if indexPath.row < yourStringCarrierArray.count {
        cell.textView.text = yourStringCarrierArray[indexPath.row] ?? "placeholder string, because there's no input here so far"
    }
}
```

I hope this will help or at least give you a new perspective, it has been a while, i coded in Swift. Feel free to ask me, if something is unclear.

Comment: hey there, thanks for helping! I tried to do it your way, please respond to the updated version above appreciate it thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use an object to save the string value, since String in swift is value type. Here is an example:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var dataArray: [CellData] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

        for _ in 0..<20 {
            dataArray.append(CellData())
        }
    }


}

extension TestViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

        cell.setData(data: dataArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var data: CellData!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        textView.text = ""
        textView.delegate = self
    }

    func setData(data: CellData) -> Void {
        self.data = data
        self.textView.text = data.stringValue
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}

extension TestTableViewCell: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        self.data.stringValue = textView.text
    }
}
```

---

```
class CellData {

    var stringValue: String = ""

}
```